# PHP Print code (print into paper)

Tags: php

Is there a PHP function to print something from a web page (inside the browser)?

I was searching in Google but the result is the `print()` function. Or any ideas, or any web programming language that you can share. I need a code to print a list of subjects from my database. Sorry for this stupid question. I don't know if that is possible.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5):

If you are talking about a web application, you can bring up the print dialog box with JavaScript using the `window.print()` function.

Without using activex or other such trickery, there is no way to automatically send something to the printer.

This is a good thing, imagine a malicious web site printing thousands of pages on your machine without your consent.

If you are running a command line php that will depend on the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

If the intention is a print preview, where the user can click an “Print this” button and the *server* will print the document you can use CUPS if you use a Linux/Apple/BSD server. http://www.cups.org/articles.php?L545+TNews+Q

Answer (score 0):

try this, you need to add php_printer.dll, then enable that extension (after restarting apache)
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printer-write.php